# Pycharm выдаёт No module named 'telebot'

Tags: python, telebot, импорт

Установил pyTelegramBotAPI, импортирую модуль telebot - программа не видит.

Устанавливал и через pycharm изнутри, и через pip в pycharm, и через pip из командной строки винды. Всё удалял, всё переустанавливал, всё апгрейдил.

Удалил вообще питон с компа, удалил пайчарм вместе со всеми настройками и прочим, всё скачал заново, всё голое, только один интерпретатор, ни одного проекта в пайчарме.
Первым же делом ставлю туда pyTelegramBotAPI, больше вообще ничего, модуль встал(был установлен из настроек в пайчарме), он отображается и в настройках, и через pip list. Но всё равно выдаёт ошибку: "No module named 'telebot'".

При этом другие библиотеки, например встроенные - "math" или скаченные - "numpy", работают прекрасно.

Прилагаю скриншот.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй сделать так `pip install --upgrade pip==21.1.2`

Comment: И если что сделайте довнгрейд модулей отсюда https://pastebin.com/XDZnK7N7

Comment: А вообще лучше перейдите на айограм с ним таких траблов нет

Comment: После даунгрейда у меня даже numpy перестал импортироваться. Поднял версию назад: numpy работает, telebot нет. Вероятно, послушаю вашего совета и попробую айограм. Раз эту проблему я решить не могу.

Comment: А вот там справа внизу у вас тот окружение выбрано, в котором вы библиотеки ставили? Окружения должны совпадать.

Answer (score 0):

Возможная пробелам (пишу в pycharm)

открываем setting (ctrl+alt+s) ищем python interpreter выбираем pip ищем telebot устанавливаем[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не та библиотека. Он правильно установил pyTelegramBotAPI, которая импортируется как telebot

Comment: я так делал, мне не помогло, помог вышеописанный мной метод